# UnsatisfiedLinkError in Android

Tags: java, android

I am having an issue referencing a library that links to a .so file.

I keep getting a UnsatisfiedLinkError:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.testapp.mobileid-2/base.apk"],
nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.testapp.mobileid-2/lib/arm, 
/system/lib, /vendor/lib, system/vendor/lib, system/vendor/lib/egl,
system/lib/hw]]] couldn't find "libusb.so"
            at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366)
```

My directory looks like this -

```
Test App
    -app
        -libs
            -armeabi
                 -libusb.so
            -armeabi-v7a
                 -libusb.so
            -libusb.jar
            -OtherLibrary.jar
        -src
        -...
```

I've tried renaming 'libs' to 'lib' based on the error message which did not work either. I can not figure it out. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I don't have enough rep to comment. Are you using Android Studio or Eclipse?

If using Android Studio, did you add the following line to your `sourceSets`?

```
 jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
```